# React native webview font size change makes text propagate outside

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a summary view where i import text from and uri inside a webview ad i inject js to change size but when i do that the text go outside the webview.

This is how the uri loads into the webview:

[image: This is how the uri loads into the webview]

and this is what i get when i change the font-size:

[image]

this is the webview :

```
  <WebView 
    key={this.state.value}
    ref={webview => this.setState({WebViewRef:webview})}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    onLoadEnd={
      this.setState({
        visibleBack:false
      })
    }
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{ uri: `http://backend.iferu.com/cleanbook.php?idbook=${this.props.product.id}` }} style={{paddingLeft:15,height:this.state.webViewHeight ,width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 50}}
    key={this.state.key}
    injectedJavaScript={jsBeforeLoad}
    onMessage={this.onMessage}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    style={{ height : this.state.webViewHeight}}    
/>
```

and this is the js im injecting to change font-size:

```
sendDataToWebView(){
    let injectedData =
    `
      // document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = '${this.state.fontSizeState}px';
      $('#takeAways').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState},
      });
      $('#recomClass').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState}
      });
      $('#summaryTitle').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState}
      });
      $('#summaryText').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState}
      });
      $('#auteurTitle').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState}
      });
      $('#auteurText').css({
        'font-size':${this.state.fontSizeState}
      });
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.scrollHeight));  
    `;
    this.state.WebViewRef.injectJavaScript(injectedData);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It only happens on Android(I'm working on the opposite, actually, to webview font size increase on iOS)

But if you want to lock the font size, you can use textZoom prop.

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#textZoom